# Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getName. - Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Like the title suggests, I have 7 URLs and I need to parse the data from those URLs into their specific sheet. On the Primary Spreadsheet I have the URLs in column[0] and the names of their sheets in column[1].
I also have a secondary spreadsheet with 7 sheets whose names match the cell values in column[1] of the primary spreadsheet.

I can't get the names in the primary spreadsheet and the sheets in the secondary spreadsheet to link. What am I doing wrong?

```
function main() {
/**
 * Grabbing URLs and Sheet Names from Master Sheet.
 */
  const archData = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1OW9RjN-kw589Uyz5Eu1Pt-ZBm5qUOvVHEtUYgwqwleg")
    .getSheets()[0]
    .getDataRange()
    .getValues()
  for (let i=0; i<archData.length; i++){
    let url = archData[i][0];
    let name = archData[i][1];
    Logger.log("Loop #%s: Sheet (%s)", i, name)
    importData(url, name)
  }
}

function importData(url, sheetName) {
    const file = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url); // get feed
    const csv = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
    const csvData = csvToArray(csv); // see below for CSVToArray function
    const sheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName(sheetName);
    sheet.clear();
    for (let i = 0; i < csvData.length; i++) {
        sheet.getRange(i + 1, 1, 1, csvData[i].length).setValues(new Array(csvData[i]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason you're using `UrlFetchApp` on the external Spreadsheets and not just opening them by URL?

Comment: Just a preference in organization; I thought calling each URL in the script looked too cluttered, so I created a function to call the URls via cells in a Spreadsheet instead.

Comment: Instead of `.getName()`, do `.getSheetByName()`.

Comment: Their is a Utilities.parseCsv() that returns a 2d array.

Comment: This `const sheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName(sheetName)` is not returning a sheet it is returning a name

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
function myFunction() {

  SpreadsheetApp.openById(`1OW9RjN-kw589Uyz5Eu1Pt-ZBm5qUOvVHEtUYgwqwleg`)
                .getSheets()[0]
                .getDataRange()
                .getValues()
                // Extract [url, sheetName]
                .map(row => [row[0], row[1]])
                // For each...
                .forEach(([url, sheetName], index) => {

                  Logger.log(`Loop #${index}: ${sheetName}`)

                  // Open external spreadsheet by url...
                  const externalSheetData = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url)
                                                  // Get all values on sheet...
                                                  .getSheets()[0] // <-- ???
                                                  .getDataRange()
                                                  .getValues()

                  // In active spreadsheet...
                  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
                                // Get corresponding sheet...
                                .getSheetByName(sheetName)
                                // Clear...
                                .clear()
                                // And set values from external spreadsheet.
                                .getRange(1, 1, externalSheetData.length, externalSheetData[0].length)
                                .setValues(externalSheetData)

                })

}
```

### Uncommented:

```
function myFunction() {

  SpreadsheetApp.openById(`1OW9RjN-kw589Uyz5Eu1Pt-ZBm5qUOvVHEtUYgwqwleg`)
                .getSheets()[0]
                .getDataRange()
                .getValues()
                .map(row => [row[0], row[1]])
                .forEach(([url, sheetName], index) => {

                  Logger.log(`Loop #${index}: ${sheetName}`)

                  const externalSheetData = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url)
                                                  .getSheets()[0] // <-- ???
                                                  .getDataRange()
                                                  .getValues()

                  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
                                .getSheetByName(sheetName)
                                .getRange(1, 1, externalSheetData.length, externalSheetData[0].length)
                                .setValues(externalSheetData)

                })

}
```